# How can I send the F4 key to a process in C#?

Tags: c#, process, keyboard, key

I am starting a process from a Windows application. When I press a button I want to simulate the pressing of key <kbd>F4</kbd> in that process. How can I do that?

[Later edit] I don't want to simulate the pressing of the <kbd>F4</kbd> key in my form, but in the process I started.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To send the F4 key to another process you will have to activate that process

http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/230693-activate-other-process suggests:

1. Get Process class instance returned by Process.Start
2. Query Process.MainWindowHandle
3. Call unmanaged Win32 API function "ShowWindow" or "SwitchToThisWindow"

You may then be able to use System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F4}") as Reed suggested to send the keystrokes to this process

EDIT:

The code example below runs notepad and sends "ABC" to it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextSendKeys
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Process notepad = new Process();
                notepad.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Notepad.exe";
                notepad.Start();

                // Need to wait for notepad to start
                notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

                IntPtr p = notepad.MainWindowHandle;
                ShowWindow(p, 1);
                SendKeys.SendWait("ABC");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit on how I can set another process active? I mean could you post a code sample?

Comment: You can avoid the Sleep using notepad.WaitForInputIdle()- That way it will work in machines other than your :-)

Comment: thanks, figured there'd be a better way, updated my answer :)

Comment: I am using this approach in a WinForms application but have found that SendWait (and Send) only seem to work once. I am calling the sending code from a button click event handler.

Comment: Still works fine for me, is your application taking the focus after the first Send?

Comment: My target application (notepad, receiving the SendKeys) takes focus. However it only appears to process the SendKeys on the first invocation of my SendKeys-sending application.

Comment: Maybe you should post this as a new question, I can't replicate it sorry

Comment: @Richard E: did you solve this "only works once" problem?

Comment: I had the "work once" problem too. What worked out for me was using Jon Raynor's answers in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421840/why-does-sendkey-send-only-work-once-in-a-while

Answer (score 13):

You can use [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F4}")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx);

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. I want to send the F4 key to the process started by my form, not to my form.

Comment: This is correct. From a note in the MSDN page linked above:

Because there is no managed method to activate another application, you can either use this class within the current application or use native Windows methods, such as FindWindow and SetForegroundWindow, to force focus on other applications. 

So you need to activate the window, then SendKeys the F4.

Comment: ...apparently line breaks in comments are stripped. The last line above (So...) is my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can focus the window (SetForegroundWindow WINAPI), and then use windows forms SendKeys to send F4.

Comment: You can change the focus programmatically **only** if the other program allows it.  Most programs do not allow it.

Comment: ShowWindow as in main example didn't work for me; only SetForegroundWindow did.