# How to send a key to another application

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I want to send a specific key (e.g. k) to another program named notepad, and below is the code that I used:

```
private void SendKey()
{
    [DllImport ("User32.dll")]
    static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

    var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
    var pointer = p.Handle;

    SetForegroundWindow(pointer);
    SendKeys.Send("k");
}
```

But the code doesn't work, what's wrong with the code?

Is it possible that I send the "K" to the notepad without notepad to be the active window? (e.g. active window = "Google chrome", notepad is in the background, which means sending a key to a background application)?

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No I don't, instead, it just send the "K" to the top window

Comment: see if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825651/how-can-i-send-the-f4-key-to-a-process-in-c

Comment: It works, but what the program does is to send the key to an already opened program, instead of starting the program programmably

Comment: Does notepad becomes foreground window ? I guess that this is a problem, see docs for SetForegroundWindow, under remarks : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: is notepad allready started when you call this method ?

Comment: yes, I'm sure notepad had started and if i'm right, notepad was the foreground window (return result 0)

Comment: worth noting the dllimport line is `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport` so without that absolute path you'd need a using line for it, and I think those two lines the dllimport line and the extern line, go within the class outside the methods.

Comment: if you add the code posted by jandex  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423234/make-a-form-not-focusable-in-c-sharp/2428108#2428108  to your form then you can sendkeys to whatever application is active.. your program/form won't take focus and nothing on your form, will take the focus..

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If notepad is already started, you should write:

```
// import the function in your class
[DllImport ("User32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

//...

Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null)
{
    IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    SendKeys.SendWait("k");
}
```

[`GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) returns an array of processes, so you should get the first one (or find the one you want).

If you want to start `notepad` and send the key, you should write:

```
Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
p.WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
SetForegroundWindow(h);
SendKeys.SendWait("k");
```

The only situation in which the code may not work is when `notepad` is started as Administrator and your application is not.

Comment: But I don't want to start the program programably, what I want to do is to send the key to an running program, is there any way to do this?

Comment: @HugoWong The only situation in which the code may not work is when `notepad` is started as Administrator and your application is not.

Comment: I just read an article about it not always working on Windows 7, which is what I'm running, the funny thing is, it works for some apps, but not the one I'm trying to dump text into.

Comment: @GlennCuevas Describe your exact situation in a new question, and I'll happily answer that.

Comment: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/setforegroundwindow.html   defines extern method SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point) as:

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

Comment: @lison Yes but they have exactly the same effect. The pinvoke.net signature is more correct, as it uses the designated constructs (`UnmanagedType.bool` is the equivalent of Win32's `BOOL` macro, which is defined as `int`). Mine is hand-converted signature, when I didn't read the entire documentation for P/Invoke :)

Comment: @Triynko I guess maybe due to security reasons, if some ill-intention people write some nasty code and start a program and write some input without the permission of the user, it could be dangerous. Just like Android, they don't have the API to turn on / off the flight mode, they can only open the settings and the user have to click it by himself

Comment: That might be true in this case, but so often I have used an API that is so needlessly complex and "security" gets the blame

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string h1;
    public string h2;
    public string m1;
    public string m2;
    public string s1;
    public string s2;

   public partial class Form1 

    hours hour = new hours();
Sendkeys.SendWait(Convert.ToString(hour.h1+hour.h2+hour.m1+hour.m2+hour.s1+hour.s2              +" "));
```

it is a simple matter of sending a classed string to  the sendkey process using the convert to string procedure

Comment: in this instance i have created a classed string sequence that sends 6 strings to the sendkey and adds a space

Comment: simply open the program using Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault(); Mohammad Dehghan has stated

Answer (score 0):

You can send anything by first copying into the clipboard and then paste the send keys ctrl+v:

```cs
Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();

if (p != null)
{
    IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    Clipboard.Clear();
    Clipboard.SetText(txtCode.Text); 
    string strClip = Clipboard.GetText();
    SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
}
```

Comment: This is original using of clipboard!