# Set (default) zoom level of IE11 programatically (i.e. via regedit)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Before running any web tests I want to ensure that the IE11 is on zoom level 100%.

Is there any way to programmatically reset the zoom level to 100%? I'm using C# and would prefer an official Microsoft API, if there is none, I guess I need to set some registry or configuration setting.

Note: I'm *not* looking for a solution for resetting the zoom level using JavaScript or HTML!

Comment: what about [SendKeys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15292175/2596334)? `alt-v, z, 0`

Comment: `ctrl-0` would be even shorter

Comment: Don't know if that's a good solution, however, unfortunately not possible at all: my web testing framework already throws an exception on IE-start if the zoom-level is not 100%. So no time for me to do any SendKeys-stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well then would not the right thing be to detect that the zoom level isn't 100% and then reset it - rather than letting the application crash because it assumes the zoom is 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Close the browser with zoom setting as 100%

Go to `RegEdit`

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom`
Change `ResetZoomOnStartup2` value to `0` (It doesn't default the zoom setting to the regular one)

OR

In windows 10, go to display settings and change the scaling to 100%

That should set the basic zoom to 100% in IE

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
 string registryKey = @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom";
 var regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(registryKey, true);
 if (regKey != null)
 {
     regKey.SetValue("ZoomFactor", unchecked((int)0x00100000), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
 }
```