# C# keyboard button send events to another form

Tags: c#, forms, button, keyboard

I need some help how to implement the following thing in C#:
I got a Form, that has a textBox. When I click into the textBox it opens another Form that is a "keyboard" I made. I has buttons like Q, W, E etc. 
When I left click the Q button for example I would like to pass that button's text into that textBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be hacky to do this. Since you need to know where the focus was before you clicked on your keyboard form. So you would need

- Your Keyboard form
- A loop that continuously gets the current focus on the screen. Lookup DllImport and GetFocus (and SetFocus)
- Once a user clicks on your keyboard form you need to set focus back to the previous application and send that keyboard event to that other application. To do that check this: [C# using Sendkey function to send a key to another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application)

Thats basically it, but some applications might not be responsive to your SendKeys feature if they are based on DirectInput for example.