# Simulating keystroke combos

Tags: c#, keyboard-events

I have created a WinForms app, and put a button in it.

I want to code an event, that whenever I click the button it will automatically simulate an ALT + 2 key press on the keyboard.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net have a class in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace that's called [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx).
It allows you to send keys to mimic keyboard hits.
You need a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll (Note: this does not have to be a winforms application for that), and then you can simply use `SendKeys.Send(%2)` to mimic a user pressing alt+2.

A full list of supported special keys can be found in the msdn page I've linked to.

Comment: Thanks ill try it soon :), also you know if it send those key in the same time? or just one after the other?

Comment: @Shaxib: every call to `Send` will send the keys you specify in the same time. so if you want to mimic the user typing *Shaxib*, you will have to use `SendKeys.Send` for each letter.

Comment: Glad to help :-) Yes, I am. you are from india, I guess?

Comment: Lol no, Israeli as well :P   There's a long story behind my nickname

Comment: @Mystra007 sure indeed XD By the way Zohar, do you know how can i hook my program to a specific proccess such as "chrome.exe"?

Comment: something like Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"). You might need to P/invoke the Windows API to send keys to it.  This thread would be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application. Note that there might be more than one chrome.exe as browser often runs several thread but that thread should give you some keywords to start your research :) Sends Zohan my regards lol