# SendKeys to another application without front

Tags: c#, winforms

I already try that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application)

And I want to do as same as that but when the process not front, 
Without `SetForegroundWindow`

Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like no, but you can try to use `SendMessage` function

Comment: how i use that to send a key

Comment: Use `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_KEYDOWN` messages