# C# code to make my program login in another one

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one little windows form program with 2 buttons , the objective is to open executables , i did it already , yet i want the program to login with my credencials in those executables , accessing to a file where my user id and password is and then writing it in the login box .

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the other program doesn't accept login credentials on their command line then consider using SendKeys to send the keystrokes directly. Check out this answer: [C# using Sendkey function to send a key to another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application)

Comment: And is it possible to access to a file text and copy the credencials from there to the executable ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You will need to do some research into file I/O in C# to understand how to implement this. The MSDN page here -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278(v=vs.110).aspx - is a good start.

Comment: Thank you , one last thing , the command to read from a text file will read everything in the file or i can say to the program to get some line of information ?

Comment: Yes. Check out the ReadLine method on the same StreamReader class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx