# Simulate Control+v key press when creating a txt file

Tags: c#, copy-paste

Hello everyone and thank you in advance.

I have copied a text and now I want to paste this text into a ".txt" what needs to be created automatically. I know the paste simulation key is as follows:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
```

On the other hand, the previous simulation key press should be included somehow within the following code (which creates a writes), but I am not sure how to do this...

```
public void writeTXT()
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
           sw.WriteLine();
        }
     }
}
```

Any comments will be welcome!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: `Clipboard.GetText()`. There's no need to futz around with simulated keypresses at all.

Comment: I didnt know the Clipboard class, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to simulate keypresses. You can access the clipboard directly:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
{
   sw.WriteLine(Clipboard.GetText());
}
```

Comment: `sw.Write()` ? avoid useless `\n` at the end and keeps the original text

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to simulate a Ctrl+V.

Use the `Clipboard` class instead.

You can find info in there :

> https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Downvoted as a) this is a link-only answer and b) the link is in French.